# Error while updating in database using dataset

Tags: c#, ado.net

While running the below code getting this error

> Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against
>   a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

Tried doing many things nothing is working. Below is the code

```
 string queryUp = "SELECT Node_A_ObjectID,Node_Z_ObjectID FROM NDDILinks";
            string myConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data source=D:\TiptonDB.mdb";
            DataSet dtup = new DataSet();
            using (OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = myConnection;
                myConnection.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryUp, myConnection);
                adp.FillSchema(dtup, SchemaType.Source, "NDDILinks");
                adp.Fill(dtup, "NDDILinks");

                dtup.Tables[0].Rows[1][0] = 2350;
                adp.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;

                OleDbCommandBuilder objCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adp);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Node_A_ObjectID", OleDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "Node_A_ObjectID");
                int a1 = adp.Update(dtup, "NDDILinks");
                dtup.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are selecting the primary key from your table `NDDILinks` ? also make sure you have defined the key in your table.

Comment: I am not selecting primary key only 2 values Node_A_ObjectID,Node_Z_ObjectID.Do i need to select primary key also ?  Yes my table has primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not selecting primary key only 2 values
>   Node_A_ObjectID,Node_Z_ObjectID.Do i need to select primary key also ?

Based on your comment on the post. You **must select the Primary key** for your UPDATE to work with the dataset, or you can specify your own UPDATE or INSERT query.  You may also see [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/5dec5633-ac84-48d9-8fd6-5c7601be4ccd) on MSDN